# Follow program execution through .DLL in hex representation

Tags: windows, debugging, dll, hex

Is there a way to follow a program's execution through DLL code in hex?

For example, I want to see what sections have just been read when I press a button. It has to work for x64 DLL's.

Thanks!

Comment: By "in hex" do you mean "in assembly"? When do you mean by "what sections have just been read"? What sections of *code* have just been loaded? Or what *data* the DLL is reading?

Comment: I'd like to know what parts of the hex/binay code (as seen in a hex editor, eg QtCreator that opens the DLL) is being read/executed

Comment: Why would you want to see the hexadecimal representation of the instructions? Why not just look at the disassembly? Any debugger will show you the hex opcodes and operands anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Load the project in visual studio.
2. Press 'Play' or F5 to start the program in the debugger.
3. You will need to eventually halt execution sometime so you can start stepping through code or assembly code. You can do this by inserting a breakpoint, or breaking the execution by hitting the break command in the visual studio IDE.
4. Once halted, you can right click in the code view window, and select "Show Disassembly". Then it will show you the machine instructions.
5. Also in the watch window in the visual studio debugger, the right click pop up menu has an option to display all variables as hexidecimal. I'm beginning to prefer hex myself lately, because I can see invalid memory patterns easier.

Comment: A DLL contains source code. albeit, machine assembly instructions types source code. So yes, the visual studio debugger can let you single step through assembly instructions even if you don't have the source code.

Comment: This seems like it might work, now to install my free student Visual Studio 2010...

Answer (score 3):

Yes you load the process into debugger and single step it.

Comment: How would this work, I only can see the function calls and I'm really not experienced with debugging :(

Comment: @rubenvb: Now's the time to get experienced with debugging.  It's doing what you want - you can set breakpoints wherever you wish, and see the assembly-language representation of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool at http://ircdb.org to log function calls arbitrary DLLs.

It's name is SocketSpy, because initially it was created for tracing winsock.dll only, but it does allow you to trace other dlls.

From http://fixunix.com/programmer/95098-tracing-library-dll-calls-win32.html

> Use Option->Default Break Point List
>   Menu to add or remove soft breakpoints
>   from attached DLLs. Put soft
>   breakpoints only at function you need
>   to maximize execution time.
>
> Soft breakpoint means that socketspy
>   does not stop at this breakpoint, only
>   log breakpoint information. Hard
>   breakpoint means that socketspy DOES
>   STOP at this breakpoint, and
>   Breakpoint dialog is opened. Specify
>   what calls should be captured ALL,
>   FROM EXE FILE or from DLLs (Combobox).
>
> Specify log file File->Open Log File
>   menu if you want to save function
>   DLLs' calls into the text file, enable
>   logging (check box).
>
> Then select a new or already action
>   process (Select Process button). The
>   tool can be used in NT/2000/XP only

Alternatively, there is StraceNT, which can trace arbitrary Dlls. It is available for free from http://www.intellectualheaven.com/default.asp?BH=projects&H=strace.htm

Comment: Sorry, I'd forgotten that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it, but I once stumble upon an Intel tool, which samples the context of the Instruction Pointer, and is able to use symbol files to convert IP to an actual function name... [VTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune/) maybe?

I guess there might be other such tools

UPDATE: aka. ["statistical profilers"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29)...

Answer (score 0):

Debugging using IDE does not show you the assembly language equivalent of the execution of an IL instruction. You need to write your own hooks to a proper disassembler.

Comment: Assuming of course he wants to debug .NET. Then of course he simply needs reflector to do that. No need to ask a question like that above.